# Play very small video files frame by frame

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, webcam, windows-media-player

I am using the service `motion` to capture some videos with my webcam in `.ogg` format. However the captured files are very small and have very bad quality. A files is about 30kb "big".

If i play them with the html5 media player, then i can see the video playing, even though it plays very fast.

However if i open the file with VLC media player or windows media player, then the file is opened and only one picture of it is showing then it immediately closes again, because it is just a few ms long.

Is there a videoplayer which allows me to open the video anyways and play it frame by frame to analyse the footage?

Comment: This question is asking for a software recommendation which is off topic here.

Comment: It is a question about computer software, so how is it off-topic, explain.

Comment: He did. As-is this "question" is simply asking for suggestions/recommendation for a piece of software that does "X" (video player that can play small files frame by frame), and those types of questions are explicitly off-topic for SU (as shown in the [help/on-tpoic section](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic)). If oyu wan tit to stay open, please edit and reword it to be a question about the actual problem (including attempted solutions) instead of (just) requesting software that does X.

Comment: "Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve."
Thats exactly what i did ... ._.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Media Player Classic Home Cinema MPC-HC ([link](https://mpc-hc.org/)) to do that. When you open the video file just stop the video, press dot (.) and then Ctrl+RightArrow to step frame by frame.